# Windows 8.1 how to automatically wrap grid items?

Tags: xaml, grid, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm building a universal app and my Win8.1 app has to show a grid of items. Normally the grid consists of 3 columns, but on smaller screens I want the items to wrap so that there are only 2 columns (or even 1). This is my code:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Regions}" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3" MinWidth="400" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                <Image Source="{Binding Code, Converter={StaticResource FlagIconConverter}, ConverterParameter='/Assets/Icons/Flags/{0}.png'}" Width="30" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NativeName}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Margin="10,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Whenever I make the app smaller, the items do not automatically wrap. I tried solving this by changing the `MaximumRowsOrColumns` property with a `VisualStateManager` but that didn't work because it couldn't access my `WrapGrid` for some reason. Changing the property from code-behind didn't work either, because again it couldn't access the WrapGrid.

I tried this with both `WrapGrid` and `ItemsWrapGrid` (what is the difference anyway?) and `ListView` and `GridView`. No difference there.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything.  It should wrap based on the available client area.  The only thing I can think of that would not make it wrap is that you put your `<GridView>` **inside a fixed width container** or a container that is size `Auto` in which you don't update the Observable Collection to notify the Grid to redraw/update itself.

For example this will not wrap.

```
<Grid Width="1000">
    <GridView x:Name="myGridView" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="5"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- DATATEMPLATE -->
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
     </GridView>
</Grid>
```

---

However get rid of that `Width=1000` and it will wrap.

Example output 3 different sizes

[image]

Comment: That's odd. The tree looks like this: `Page` -> `Grid` -> `GridView`. The Grid column it's in has a width of Auto. There are no fixed widths. Still, when I make the windows smaller it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/huNUA6Q.png.

Comment: Hmm, found the issue. It was because I put the wrapgrid inside 1 column where I have 3 columns (so an extra column on each side of the wrapgrid. After I set the columnspan to 3, it started wrapping like it should. If you can update your answer to include this I will accept it :)

Comment: Sweet :) `Auto` size will have the same effect as fixed size.  The grid will only calculate the size once....unless the collection if one is bound changes.  So resizing the App will not effect it.  Change your `Auto` to `*` and you can resize your App and it will change the wrap the grid.  :),  I will update the solution to avoid Auto as well.