# How to Display the Listview items horizontally in XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

am developing a Windows Store 8.1 app using C# and xaml.
I have a UI requirement like below[image]

I have a list of items to display which has to be grouped, so for this i took a listview and i have done the grouping, its working fine.The listview items are aligned vertically but i want to align them horizontally like in the picture.
I have added the below code to the listview but it is not working.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="1" HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Stretch"
                  Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Can someone please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have set the MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" in the ItemsWrapGrid, it works fine. Please check my code to see if you have missed something.
In the MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" ItemsPath="showitem" x:Name="cvs" IsSourceGrouped="True"></CollectionViewSource>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView Width="500" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" Orientation="Horizontal"></ItemsWrapGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <TextBox Width="50" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Width="400" Height="60" Background="Blue">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding id}" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>  
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

In the MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public class test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class testlist

{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<test> showitem { get; set; }
}
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        List<testlist> mylist = new List<testlist>();
        testlist testlist = new testlist();
        testlist.id = "group1";
        testlist.showitem = new List<test>();
        testlist.showitem.Add(new test() { Name = "Test1" });
        testlist.showitem.Add(new test() { Name = "Test2" });
        mylist.Add(testlist);

        testlist testlist1 = new testlist();
        testlist1.id = "group1";
        testlist1.showitem = new List<test>();
        testlist1.showitem.Add(new test() { Name = "Test3" });
        testlist1.showitem.Add(new test() { Name = "Test4" });
        mylist.Add(testlist1);

        this.cvs.Source = mylist;

    }
}
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just need to set MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" basically you want to start wrapping at 2 elements. Set to one, it'll just wrap after one element and is no different from a vertical stack panel.

Then you probably need to tweak the width.

[Windows 8.1 how to automatically wrap grid items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953070/windows-8-1-how-to-automatically-wrap-grid-items)

Comment: It did not work out, it works pretty well when there is no grouping. But when i group the data then its not working

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782294/uwp-grouped-gridview-with-wrapgrid you can probably use a grid view instead of a listview